# C-std headers containing helper functions for system, user and kernel times?

Tags: cpu, time, glibc, linux-headers

Basically, I am working with Nvidia's new github repos and trying to compile them in a cross-platform setup.  Specifically, I am trying to compile them on Fedora 33.

I have run into an issue:

```
In file included from /home/chris/.../sample_example.cpp:55:
/home/chris/.../nvml_monitor.hpp:19:10: fatal error: cfgmgr32.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <cfgmgr32.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `cfgmgr32.h` appears to be a windows-specific library.

Within the file `nvml_monitor.hpp`, it looks like I can get away with disabling most of the windows content.  But, I think the following Windows-specific function is going to be useful:

```
  float getCpuLoad()
  {
    static uint64_t _previousTotalTicks = 0;
    static uint64_t _previousIdleTicks  = 0;

    FILETIME idleTime, kernelTime, userTime;
    GetSystemTimes(&idleTime, &kernelTime, &userTime);

    auto FileTimeToInt64 = [](const FILETIME& ft) {
      return (((uint64_t)(ft.dwHighDateTime)) << 32) | ((uint64_t)ft.dwLowDateTime);
    };

    auto totalTicks = FileTimeToInt64(kernelTime) + FileTimeToInt64(userTime);
    auto idleTicks  = FileTimeToInt64(idleTime);

    uint64_t totalTicksSinceLastTime = totalTicks - _previousTotalTicks;
    uint64_t idleTicksSinceLastTime  = idleTicks - _previousIdleTicks;

    float result = 1.0f - ((totalTicksSinceLastTime > 0) ? ((float)idleTicksSinceLastTime) / totalTicksSinceLastTime : 0);

    _previousTotalTicks = totalTicks;
    _previousIdleTicks  = idleTicks;

    return result * 100.f;
  }
```

---

What I am looking for is not anyone to "do the work" or anything -- just a place to start or a thread to pull on.

When searching for linux solutions in this problem space, the results are obfuscated by shell-level responses.  But, instead, what I am looking for are the `C` headers which provide interfaces and handles for this information.

Are there any specific linux headers similar in purpose to the `cfgmgr32.h` header in windows?  If not, are there searchable linux kernel resources for discovering these headers or functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, this information is available in [`/proc/stat`’s `cpu` line](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and is usually parsed from there — I don’t think there’s a user-space-accessible function which will provide the same information.

The values in that line give the time spent user mode, the time spent in user mode with low priority, the time spent in system mode, the time spent in the idle task, among other times; see the link above for details.

Functions are available to retrieve time information for the current process and/or its children; for example [POSIX’s `getrusage`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getrusage.html) and [`times`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/times.html).